Partition induced by a cover
Let $X$ be a set and let $(Y_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of (not necessarily pairwise disjoint) subsets covering $X$,
$$ X = \bigcup_{i\in I} Y_i.$$
For any subset $J \subseteq I$, we then define
$$ Y_J := \bigcap_{i \in J} Y_i \cap \bigcap_{i \notin J} X \setminus Y_i . $$
One checks easily that $(Y_J)_{J \subseteq I}$ is a partition of $X$ (i.e., a cover by a pairwise disjoint family of sets).
However, this partition is indexed by the power set of $I$, which has a strictly larger cardinality than $I$ itself.
Q: What is an example of a covering $(Y_i)_{i \in I}$, where $I$ is countable, but there are uncountably many $J \subseteq I$ such that $Y_J$ is non-empty? Or can this not happen for some reason?

You probably mean $\cap$ in the definition of $Y_J$, not $\cup$?

Yes, corrected. Thanks for your answer!

Let $X$ be the set of all infinite 0-1 sequences except the all-0 sequence. Let $Y_j$ be the set of sequences with $j$-th term equal to 1. Then every $Y_J$ contains exactly one element.
